# Snapping in HorizontalScrollView inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, horizontalscrollview

I want to achieve Snapping effect in HorizontalScrollView inside fragment i.e when the user scrolls horizontally the first item (item visible > 50%) HorizontalScrollView need to move to the next item completely. What I want is  when the user scrolls horizontally the first item more than 50% I want to show only second child view. In this way if the user scrolls horizontally the 2nd item, I want show only third child view.

I have used below **smoothScrollTo**().

```
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        homeBinding.sevenDaysCaseHistoryScroll.setMinimumWidth(width);
        homeBinding.sevenDaysEczemaVsWeatherScroll.setMinimumWidth(width);
        homeBinding.sevenDaysEczemaVsCareRoutineScroll.setMinimumWidth(width);
        homeBinding.sevenDaysEczemaVsTriggersScroll.setMinimumWidth(width);

        homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if(homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() < (width/2)){
                    sevenDaysShowCaseHistoryDot();
                    homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
                } else if(homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() > (width/2) && homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() < (2*width)-(width/2)){
                    sevenDaysShowEczemaVsWeatherDot();
                    homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.smoothScrollTo(width,0);
                } else if(homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() > (2*width)-(width/2) && homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() < (3*width)-(width/2)){
                    sevenDaysShowEczemaVsCareRoutineDot();
                    homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.smoothScrollTo(2*width,0);
                } else if(homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() > (3*width)-(width/2)){
                    sevenDaysShowEczemaVsTriggersDot();
                    homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.smoothScrollTo(3*width,0);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Current behavior is when the user scrolls horizontally the first item (item visible > 50%) user can see first child view and second child view both like grid view. But  I want single child view only.

In XML file I have HorizontalScrollView where One parent LinearLayout and 4 child linear layout is there. Sample layout is given below.

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sevenDaysHorizontalView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sevenDaysGraphLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sevenDaysCaseHistoryScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sevenDaysEczemaVsWeatherScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">



        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sevenDaysEczemaVsCareRoutineScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sevenDaysEczemaVsTriggersScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

What can be done to solve the issue?

[image]

Comment: Using a ViewPager would take care of the snapping. You can add your own transitions by implementing a custom ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.

Comment: @dharms thanks for your suggestion. It would be great if could give any solution by using Horizontal scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

At last this solved my problem.

```
homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch ( event.getAction( ) ) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if(homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() < (width/2)){
                            sevenDaysShowCaseHistoryDot();
                            homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.scrollTo(0,0);
                        } else if(homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() > (width/2) && homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() < (2*width)-(width/2)){
                            sevenDaysShowEczemaVsWeatherDot();
                            homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.scrollTo(width,0);
                        } else if(homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() > (2*width)-(width/2) && homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() < (3*width)-(width/2)){
                            sevenDaysShowEczemaVsCareRoutineDot();
                            homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.scrollTo(2*width,0);
                        } else if(homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.getScrollX() > (3*width)-(width/2)){
                            sevenDaysShowEczemaVsTriggersDot();
                            homeBinding.sevenDaysHorizontalView.scrollTo(3*width,0);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        })
```

;